# Running C++ in Eclipse on MacOS

Tags: eclipse, macos

I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developer on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6. When I build a project (HelloWorld Project) I see a message:

"xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
"make clean" terminated with exit code 1. Build might be incomplete.

22:30:31 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 74ms)"

And I can't run the program

Answer (score 0):

... *three years later* ...

Try installing the Xcode command-line tools by running `xcode-select --install`.